# Android - restore activity stack after process killed?

Tags: android, android-activity

From my research on the internet, I found that if my app process is killed by the system, next time the user goes back to it, the system will restore the activity stack. That is, any activity on top of the root activity remains there, but only the very top one is recreated. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375720/android-destroying-activities-killing-processes))

I tested this by killing my process in monitor (ddms). I don't see activity stack restored. Only the root activity appears. So anything I'm missing here? What else do I need to implement for the stack to be restored?

I found the "persistableMode" attribute. Is that what I need? [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#persistableMode)

Or the android:alwaysRetainTaskState? [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always)

Comment: Please add the relevant links (from your research) to the question.

Comment: It's worth noting that the activity stack is *not* restored if the app is killed by a swipe from recents.  In that case, it restarts from the launcher activity.

Comment: Have you got a better understanding of this question? I have the same question but can't find a reasonable explanation.

Comment: I'm using Appcelerator Titanium. I thought it's Titanium's mechanism that prevents the activity stack from restoring. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

mostly it **depends on flag which was used to launch intents**

for example

```
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 /** 
 * If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
 * history stack.
 *
 * This flag is generally used by activities that want
 * to present a "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of
 * separate things that can be done, which otherwise run completely
 * independently of the activity launching them.
 */
```

for more info see API doc:

[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

see also:

- Activity/Fragment lifecycle
- [Handling affinities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Affinities)
- [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))
- [Retain Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always)
- [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)