# Does android kill apps by itself?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app which is made with phonegap and I am testing on android.  I am having problems where my app will have stopped when I wasn't using my phone, so I lose all my logs when I check it later.  Although it isn't just the logs which is a problem, I need the app to not stop for other reasons also.

just to be clear, by stopped I mean when I click on the app icon again it will start the app with the loading screen instead of opening it to where I was before like it normally would.

So what I would like to know is, why would it be stopping? Is there likely to be an error which is making it crash or does android kill apps that are not active for a certain time or something else?

Comment: Yes. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android destroying activities, killing processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375720/android-destroying-activities-killing-processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. for officially android version, it not kill application when you not use the phone. but background application may be killed if the foreground application require more memory. please check the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle).

so maybe there is some background service declare self as foreground(start with [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))), and it need much memory.
or, some system level service need much memory, i think.