# Android when fragment is removed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a FrameLayout and put there some fragments by click on button, next click should remove fragment from FrameLayout, I do this by `removeAllViews()` (FrameLayout is in another Fragment so translaction method is in Activity).
I need to do some action when `removeAllViews()` starts and have to do it in Fragment class but something goes wrong.

I tried:
`OnDestroy()`
`OnDestroyView()`
`OnPause()`
in Fragment class

but it works like:

1. put Fragment in FrameLayout (from Activity)
2. use `removeAllViews()` (from Activity)
3. there is no Fragment in FrameLayout (is clear) but nothing else happens and methods are not working
4. put new Fragment in FrameLayout (from Activity) - now all methods (`OnDestroy()` from Fragment class) works (probably it's real time to `destroy` old fragment)

How is it possible to 'get moment' when Fragment is not exists for user? I want to send some information to server if user hides Fragment.

@Edit3
code from method from Activity where I want to make translaction

```
public void showProductsList(String productType,int containerID){

        List<String> prodNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Long> prodIds = new ArrayList<Long>();

            DatabaseDAOProdProtein dao = new DatabaseDAOProdProtein(getApplicationContext());
            dao.open();
            List<DatabaseProduct> productList = dao.getAllProducts();
            for(int i=0;i<productList.size();i++){
                prodNames.add(productList.get(i).getName());
                prodIds.add(productList.get(i).getId());
            }
            dao.close();

        ProductsList productsList = new ProductsList(productType,prodNames,prodIds);

        productsList.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"action1 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"action2 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"action3 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(containerID, productsList).commit();
    }
```

I used this method in another Fragment by:

`((MainActivity) getContext()).showProductsList("carb", carbContainer.getId());`

there is an error:

`Error:(560, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(<anonymous OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener>)`

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> "How is it possible to 'get moment' when Fragment is not exists for
>   user? I want to send some information to server if user hides
>   Fragment."

I now know you did not mean "hide", so just use  the `OnDestroy()` method.

Try this to trigger the "hide"

```
View topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

You cannot go into stopped state while Fragment (Activity) is visible. [Android destroying activities, killing processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375720/android-destroying-activities-killing-processes)

The best way to make sure something runs via a view is to run it via a post:

```
topLevelLayout.post(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
        topLevelLayout.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

To get notified of system UI visibility changes, register an `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` to your `view` (fragment).

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"action0 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Fragment your_frag = new ProductsList(productType,prodNames,prodIds);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(containerID,your_frag).commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();//make sure onCreateView has executed
        your_frag.getRootView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"action1 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"action2 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"action3 " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

A typical fragment looks like this:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    View                        mRootView     = null;
    public HomeFragment(){}//null constructor

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return mRootView ;
    }
public View getRootView ()
{
    return mRootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Put the listener on your fragment when you create it (the rootView).

Comment: I create it in Activity (edited my post again). Could you explain me how to put listener please?

Comment: Is this (the code I've added) making sense to you ?

Comment: Is there any way to use this method outside the `OnCreate()`? (I dont want to load fragment when activity is started, just by `((MainActivity) getContext()).showProductsList("protein", proteinContainer.getId());` in another fragment)

Comment: Yes you can do it where you want.

Comment: So should I put `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` in method in Activity where I want to make translaction? edited my post for current code

Comment: Once you create the fragment (where ever you want) attach the Listener to it's rootView, then execute the transaction on the fragment.

Comment: Yes you need to use the rootView (look at the code I commented out), add the getRootView method to your fragment, OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener operateds on a View.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127458/discussion-between-jon-goodwin-and-barmi).