# Java android kill apk and background service

Tags: java, android

I want to kill my apk and background services I try did this:

```
 finishAffinity();
                   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    am.killBackgroundProcesses("pl.eltegps.inwentaryzja.offline");

                int pid = Process.myPid();
                Process.killProcess(pid);
                System.exit(1);
```

But it doesn't work . When I check how I have minimalize apk I see my apk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597017/2551236

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android destroying activities, killing processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375720/android-destroying-activities-killing-processes)

Comment: @Vihar I chec this answer and it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong but all the time I see this apk in apk which is work

Comment: your finishAffinity() method executes before your code does so there may be something in that method.Is the code I shared working?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works :

```
Intent i = new Intent(LFRFIDActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.putExtra("isExitAction", true);
                    startActivity(i);
```

and in splash activity I do this :

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            Intent i = getIntent();
            Boolean isExit = i.getBooleanExtra("isExitAction",false);
            if(isExit){
                this.finish();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
```