# How to instruct the OS not to recreate activity after application has been idle for hours, but to start fresh instead?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have read both solutions here:

[Prevent Activity Stack from being Restored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423571/prevent-activity-stack-from-being-restored)

But I hope there is a more elegant way to solve this.

Here is where my problem originates.
I have an Activity that has a View Pager with Fragments
Those fragments are inner classes and for some reason inner Fragments should be static.
The fragments however, use a lot of stuff from the parent Activity, that is not static, and cannot be accessed from a static context. I tried passing them as arguments, but one of the arguments is the ViewPager itself and it cannot be serialized or accessed from a static context.
If the app has been idle for hours, the Activity is recreated instead of started fresh, and the non-static inner class Fragment crashes.

My activity does not need to remember its state from 5 hours ago. I want it to not be restored whenever the app is brought back to foreground again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution, it is so simple! (a bit hacky though)

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

}
```

No call to super, so the OS has no information to use when attempting to restore the activity state, so it builds it anew altoghether.